# What is the meaning of the Mathew words to Ray in phone?

Tags: meaning

In ***[A Walk Among the Tombstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Walk_Among_the_Tombstones_(film))***, Actually Mathew has to save the girl lucy in the hands of Ray who is kidnapper,

Now kidnapper wants money & so Mathew defining the place for collect the money through phone.

> Mathew: You check the money. When you're satisfied, you let the girl
>   go.Your man takes off with the cash.You and I wait until you feel
>   good.Then we go home.
>
> Ray: You could grab me.
>
> Mathew: **You'll have that knife you keep talking about, a gun, too,
>   if you want one.**

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you find confusing in the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You'll have that knife you keep talking about, a gun, too, if you want one.

As far I as I can tell from the context, and not having seen the movie, Ray is not sure if he can trust Matthew. Matthew is trying to convince Ray that Ray can trust Matthew. It seems that Matthew, with the above sentence, is telling Ray that Ray can have a knife and/or a gun while Ray's man "takes off with the cash."

Basically, Matthew is telling Ray that Ray can be armed while they wait - "You could grab me" shows that Ray doesn't trust Matthew, and Matthew saying the above tells Ray that Ray will be able to defend himself.

> You'll have that knife *you keep talking about*

The "you keep talking about" probably means that Ray was boasting about his knife a lot earlier in the movie.